# CTFS of sine signal appended to dead signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have a signal which is a combination of sine signal and dead signal (0) as defined below. It is periodic with period 1. 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& sin(2*pi*1000*t) \enspace for \enspace 0<t<1/10 \nonumber \\
     &=& 0 \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace for \enspace1/10 < t < 1 \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
 [image: Image for reference]

Since it is periodic and continuous, Continuous Time Fourier Transform exists. How to find it? I tried the below way and the answer is too complex. Is there any other way or am I doing something wrong?

**My Solution:** 
$$T=1$$
$$w_0=2*\pi/T = 2*\pi$$
$$X(k)=1/T * \int_0^T x(t)*exp(-jkw_0t) \, dt$$

On solving I got,
$$X(k)=\frac{1}{4*\pi} * \left\{ exp(-j2*\pi*k/10) * \left( \frac{exp(j200*\pi)}{k-1000} - \frac{exp(-j200*\pi)}{k+1000} \right) - \frac{2000}{k^2-1000000} \right\} $$

Here is a photo for reference on how I arrived to this equation. [image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems your calculation is correct. I do not think there is a simpler way of making this calculation.

Comment: @Hugocito Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer looks correct, but it doesn't provide much for one's intuition to verify its correctness, unfortunately.

You have a "sine multiplied by a shifted rectangle", so your Fourier Transform/Series coefficients should intuitively be something like "a pair of delta functions convolved with a modulated sinc() function".

Starting from your intermediate step

$$\begin{align*}X(k) &= \dfrac{1}{2j}\left[\dfrac{e^{-j2\pi(k-1000)t}}{-j2\pi(k-1000)}-\dfrac{e^{-j2\pi(k+1000)t}}{-j2\pi(k+1000)}\right]^{\frac{1}{10}}_0 \\
\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2j}\left[\dfrac{e^{-j2\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}-1}{-j2\pi(k-1000)}-\dfrac{e^{-j2\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}-1}{-j2\pi(k+1000)}\right]\\
\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2j}\left[e^{-j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{-j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}-e^{j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}}{-j2\pi(k-1000)}\\
-e^{-j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{-j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}-e^{j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}}{-j2\pi(k+1000)}\right]\\
\\
&=\dfrac{1}{20j}\left[e^{-j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}-e^{-j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}}{2j\pi(k-1000)\frac{1}{10}}\\
-e^{-j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}-e^{-j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}}{2j\pi(k+1000)\frac{1}{10}}\right]\\
\\
&=\dfrac{-j}{20}\left(e^{-j\frac{\pi}{10}(k-1000)}\cdot\mathrm{sinc}\left[\dfrac{\pi}{10}(k-1000)\right]\\
-e^{-j\frac{\pi}{10}(k+1000)}\cdot\mathrm{sinc}\left[\dfrac{\pi}{10}(k+1000)\right]\right)\\
\\
&=\dfrac{1}{10}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{10}k}\mathrm{sinc}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{10}k\right) *\dfrac{j}{2}\left[\delta(k+1000) - \delta(k-1000)\right]
\end{align*}$$

Where $*$ denotes convolution, and $\mathrm{sinc}()$ is the non-normalized sinc function.  This is the form of the result that my intuition predicted.

By the way, with the proper selection of the origin and period, such as having the center of the pulse at 0 and taking the base period from $-\frac{1}{2}$ to $+\frac{1}{2}$, you can get rid of the $e^{-j\frac{\pi}{10}k}$ modulation term.  That simplifies the expression slightly.

Comment: Wow! Elegant answer. Thank you. It took me a little time to understand. Intuition that it should be convolution was the best. And, I think you have a typo "Staring from your...". Shouldn't it be "Starting"?

Comment: Thanks.  No, that wasn't a typo.  I started from an intermediate step in your work from the image of your work that you posted.  What it really means is that I was too lazy to verify that the preceding steps were correct.  :)  On a cursory read, they look correct though.

Comment: I meant it should be "starting", not "staring" :P (You've missed a 't')

Comment: Oops.  Fixed.  Thank you.